# VBA For Each, Copy offset & paste in next space in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that's been messed up because of a file type conversion. There are a lot of blank rows and columns and I want to clean it up and extract the information I need. I receive this report regularly so I would like to automate this process.

I want to look in Column "C" for the word "Part", and when I find each instance of it, I want to "Move up 1 and over 3", copy that cell and add it to a list in column "A" of another tab.

Below is my code, when it runs, nothing happens. Not even an error message.

```
Sub EPICSPriceUpdate()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.UnMerge
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:AZ").RowHeight = 15
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:AZ").ColumnWidth = 4
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Font.Name = "Calibri"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Font.Size = 11
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Font.Bold = False
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Font.Italic = False
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Font.Underline = False
'Worksheets("Sheet1").Borders.LineStyle = xlNone

Worksheets("Output").Range("A1") = "Part Number"
Worksheets("Output").Range("B1") = "Die Number"
Worksheets("Output").Range("C1") = "Length"
Worksheets("Output").Range("D1") = "Weight"
Worksheets("Output").Range("E1") = "Price"

Dim ptn As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim Rptn As Range


Set Rptn = Worksheets("Output").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) 'last cell in Column A with data
Set ptn = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

 For Each cel In ptn
        If cel.Value = "PART" Then
            cel.Value.Offset(1, 3).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Output").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1)
        End If
    Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: `cel.Value.Offset(1, 3)` - remove the `.Value`.

Comment: @BigBen I made that correction, and now I get the error "Application-defined of object-defined error" for the line `cel.Offset(1, 3).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Output").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1)`

Comment: `Destination:=Worksheets("Output").Cells(Worksheets("Output").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub EPICSPriceUpdate()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long, n As Long
    Dim rngC As Range, cel As Range
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        With .Cells
            .UnMerge
            With .Font
                .Name = "Calibri"
                .Size = 11
                .Bold = False
                .Italic = False
                .Underline = False
            End With
        End With
        'Worksheets("Sheet1").Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
        .Range("A:AZ").RowHeight = 15
        .Range("A:AZ").ColumnWidth = 4
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngC = .Range("C1:C" & lastrow)
    End With
         
    With Worksheets("Output")
        .Range("A1:E1") = Split("Part Number;Die Number;Length;Weight;Price", ";")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
        For Each cel In rngC
            If LCase(cel.Value) = "part" Then
                n = n + 1
                cel.Offset(1, 3).Copy .Range("A" & lastrow).Offset(n)
            End If
        Next
    End With
    MsgBox n & " rows copied to Output", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: *Move up 1 over 3* would suggest `.Offset(-1, 3)`.